# Difference between "measurement" and "measuring"

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference between the nouns *measurement* and *measuring*? Can I say *the measurement has stopped* the same way I can say *the measuring has stopped*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, you have different complements available. The verb *measuring* simply takes a direct object. The noun *measurement* and the gerundial noun *measuring* take PP complements headed by *of*. Thus you have:

> *Measuring **the elephant** was dangerous.* (verb)

but:

> *The measuring **of the elephant** was fraught with danger.* (gerundial noun)
>
> *The measurement **of the elephant** went surprisingly well.* (noun)

Comment: One can also say 'Measuring the elephant...' (gerunds are more likely without the article).

Comment: Sure. The determiner isn't relevant. I suppose I shouldn't have given contrasting determiners in the example.

Answer (score 4):

For one, *measurement* is a noun, measuring is a *gerund*.

> "the measurement has stopped" refers to the process called measurement.

whereas

> "the measuring has stopped" refers to the action of measuring in a modified way, which is why that part of speech is called a gerund.

Both sentences convey the same meaning. However, one refers to an object and the other indirectly to an action.

Comment: Which version refers to an object? Aren't both involving an action? (just looking for a clrification)

Comment: @Mitch: 'measurement'

Answer (score 1):

The verb measuring simply takes a direct object. The noun measurement and the gerundial noun measuring take PP complements headed by of.