# Mass measuring vs Measuring mass

Tags: word-choice, verbs, meaning-in-context, gerunds

I have a table of Measuring Equipment, which is NOT in English. There is a column called ***Parameter Measured***, where the following is specified:

- Refractive index measuring
- Mass Measuring
- Optical rotation Measuring.

That's how I translated it.

So, can you tell me whether it is correct or not, because I can't understand the difference between all these, when "***measurement***" is to be used, and when the gerund nouns or verbs with "***-ing"*** to be used...

I have already read this: [Difference between "measurement" and "measuring"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52567/difference-between-measurement-and-measuring)

But still, can't understand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever wrote that column:

> **Parameter Measured** 
>   Refractive index measuring 
>   Mass Measuring 
>   Optical rotation Measuring

probably wishes that they had written:

> **Parameter Measured** 
>   Refractive index 
>   Mass 
>   Optical rotation

Those instances of "measuring" look like side-effects of inaccurate translation
and/or, more likely,
remnants from sentences that were edited to become a column.

In any case, "measurement" would be more approriate than "measuring,"
if the column header were different:

> **Equipment Function** 
>   Refractive index measurement 
>   Mass measurement 
>   Optical rotation measurement

Comment: Thank you very much! I read your answer on that day, but didn't know how to thank you. Now I see how))